# how to compare date with todays date ? where date is in format dd-mm-yyyy?

Tags: javascript, date

how to compare date with the today's date where date is in format dd-mm-yyyy

```
var sdate = document.getElementById('datepicker-example2').value;
if (Date.parse(document.getElementById("datepicker-example2").value) < Date.parse(dateToday.getDate() + "/" + dateToday.getmonth() + "/" + dateToday.getYear())) {
    alert("dsd");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [**Date.now()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now)

```
var sdate = document.getElementById('datepicker-example2').value;
if (Date.parse(sdate) < Date.now()) {
    alert("dsd");
}
```

Also I dont see why you retrieve the datepickers value second time while you have stored it in the first place. Its better to use the stored one.

Comment: will it work with dd-mm-yyyy format and i am using this code in $j("#btnsvSave").bind("click", function() {}

Answer (score 0):

```
date = new Date()
```

is today's date. Use the different methods of the javascript date objects to collect the month, day, and year from today and the date you are comparing,

http://www.comptechdoc.org/independent/web/cgi/javamanual/javadate.html

```
getMonth ( date ) + "-" + getDay ( date ) + "-" + getYear ( date )
```

That point you in the right direction.

Comment: will it work with dd-mm-yyyy format and i am using this code in $j("#btnsvSave").bind("click", function() {}

Answer (score 0):

Not super accurate but this will get you time difference in days between two dates. Invert the operands for future dates. Of course the time conversion could be better but you get the idea:

```
var today = new Date();
var date = new Date('10/23/12')
var diff = ~~(((today.getTime() - date.getTime()) * 2.76e-7) / 24);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var currentDate = Date.now();
if (currentDate > date2.getTime()) {
    alert("The current date is after the second date!");
}
```

The `now()` method returns the milliseconds elapsed since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC up until now as a number.

The `getTime()` returns the Milliseconds since midnight January 1, 1970

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vce4U/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Parse your date :

```
   var m = date.match (/(\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d\d\d)/);
```

Create a new date object for that date :

```
   if (m) {// check if date was matched  
     m = new Date (+m[3], +m[2] - 1, +m[1]);
```

And compare with todays date :

```
     if ((new Date ()).getTime () < m.getTime ()) {
       ...
     }
   } else { // Bad date format

   }
```